# How to better deal with INSERT if new, UPDATE if exists (70million rows)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

So I have a big cursor with similar parts. it looks like this:

```
    set nocount on;

    Declare
            @linha VarChar(1200),
            @TipoRegistro VarChar(1),
            @Cnpj VarChar(14),
            @CnpjCpfSocio VarChar(14),
            @CnaeSecundaria VarChar(14),
            @Contador Int,
            @TotalRegistros Int,
            @TotalRegistros1 Int,
            @TotalRegistros2 Int,
            @TotalRegistros6 Int

    Select @Contador = 0,
            @TotalRegistros  = 0,
            @TotalRegistros1 = 0,
            @TotalRegistros2 = 0,
            @TotalRegistros6 = 0

    Declare cCarga Cursor fast_forward
        For Select importado As Linha
        From Import;

    Open cCarga;
    Fetch Next From cCarga Into @linha;

    While (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    Begin
        set @Contador = @Contador + 1;
        set @TotalRegistros = @TotalRegistros + 1

        if (@Contador = 1000)
        begin
            print @TotalRegistros;
            Set @Contador = 0;
        end;

        select @TipoRegistro = SUBSTRING(@linha,1,1);

        -- Layout Socio
        if (@TipoRegistro = '2')
        begin
            Set @TotalRegistros2 = @TotalRegistros2 + 1;

            select @Cnpj = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,4,14))), @CnpjCpfSocio = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,169,14)));

            If Exists (Select Id From Socio Where Cnpj = @Cnpj and CnpjCpfSocio = @CnpjCpfSocio)
            Begin
                Update Socio with (tablock)
                    Set TipoRegistro = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,1,1)))
                        ,IndicadorFullDiario = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,2,1)))
                        ,TipoAtualizacao = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,3,1)))
                        ,IdentificadorSocio = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,18,1)))
                        ,NomeSocioRazaoSocial = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,19,150)))
                        ,CodigoQualificacaoSocio = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,183,2)))
                        ,PercentualCapitalSocial = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,185,5)))
                        ,DataEntradaSociedade = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,190,8)))
                        ,CodigoPaisSocio = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,198,3)))
                        ,NomePaisSocio = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,201,70)))
                        ,CpfRepresentanteLegal = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,271,11)))
                        ,NomeRepresentante = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,282,60)))
                        ,CodigoQualificacaoRepresentanteLegal = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,342,2)))
                        ,Filler = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,344,855)))
                        ,FimRegistro = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,1200,1)))
                    Where Cnpj = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,4,14)))
                        And CnpjCpfSocio = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,169,14)));
            End
            Else
            Begin
                Insert Into Socio with (tablock) (TipoRegistro,IndicadorFullDiario,TipoAtualizacao,Cnpj,IdentificadorSocio,NomeSocioRazaoSocial,CnpjCpfSocio,CodigoQualificacaoSocio,PercentualCapitalSocial,DataEntradaSociedade,CodigoPaisSocio,NomePaisSocio,CpfRepresentanteLegal,NomeRepresentante,CodigoQualificacaoRepresentanteLegal,Filler,FimRegistro)
                select rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,1,1))) as TipoRegistro
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,2,1))) as IndicadorFullDiario
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,3,1))) as TipoAtualizacao
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,4,14))) as Cnpj
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,18,1))) as IdentificadorSocio
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,19,150))) as NomeSocioRazaoSocial
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,169,14))) as CnpjCpfSocio
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,183,2))) as CodigoQualificacaoSocio
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,185,5))) as PercentualCapitalSocial
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,190,8))) as DataEntradaSociedade
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,198,3))) as CodigoPaisSocio
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,201,70))) as NomePaisSocio
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,271,11))) as CpfRepresentanteLegal
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,282,60))) as NomeRepresentante
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,342,2))) as CodigoQualificacaoRepresentanteLegal
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,344,855))) as Filler
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,1200,1))) as FimRegistro
            --End;

            Goto Continuar;
        end;

        -- Layout Principal
        if (@TipoRegistro = '1')
        begin
            Set @TotalRegistros1 = @TotalRegistros1 + 1;

            select @Cnpj = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,4,14)));

            if Exists (Select Cnpj From Empresa Where Cnpj = @Cnpj)
            Begin
                Update Empresa with (tablock)
                    Set TipoRegistro = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,1,1)))
                        ,IndicadorFullDiario = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,2,1)))
                        ,TipoAtualizacao = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,3,1)))
                        ,IdentificadorMatrizFilial = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,18,1)))
                        ,RazaoSocialNomeEmpresarial = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,19,150)))
                        ,NomeFantasia = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,169,55)))
                        ,SituacaoCadastral = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,224,2)))
                        ,DataSituacaoCadastral = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,226,8)))
                        ,MotivoSituacaoCadastral = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,234,2)))
                        ,NomeCidadeExterior = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,236,55)))
                        ,CodigoPais = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,291,3)))
                        ,NomePais = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,294,70)))
                        ,CodigoNaturezaJuridica = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,364,4)))
                        ,DataInicioAtividade = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,368,8)))
                        ,CnaeFiscal = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,376,7)))
                        ,DescricaoTipoLogradouro = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,383,20)))
                        ,Logradouro = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,403,60)))
                        ,Numero = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,463,6)))
                        ,Complemento = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,469,156)))
                        ,Bairro = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,625,50)))
                        ,Cep = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,675,8)))
                        ,Uf = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,683,2)))
                        ,CodigoMunicipio = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,685,4)))
                        ,Municipio = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,689,50)))
                        ,Ddd1 = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,739,4)))
                        ,Telefone1 = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,743,8)))
                        ,Ddd2 = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,751,4)))
                        ,Telefone2 = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,755,8)))
                        ,NuDddFax = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,763,4)))
                        ,NuFax = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,767,8)))
                        ,CorreioEletronico = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,775,115)))
                        ,QualificacaoResponsavel = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,890,2)))
                        ,CapitalSocialEmpresa = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,892,14)))
                        ,PorteEmpresa = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,906,2)))
                        ,OpcaoPeloSimples = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,908,1)))
                        ,DataOpcaoPeloSimples = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,909,8)))
                        ,DataExclusaoSimples = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,917,8)))
                        ,OpcaoPeloMei = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,925,1)))
                        ,SituacaoEspecial = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,926,23)))
                        ,DataSituacaoEspecial = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,949,8)))
                        ,Filler = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,957,243)))
                        ,FimDeRegistro = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,1200,1)))
                    Where Cnpj = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,4,14)))
            End
            Else
            Begin
                Insert Into Empresa with (tablock) (TipoRegistro,IndicadorFullDiario,TipoAtualizacao,Cnpj,IdentificadorMatrizFilial,RazaoSocialNomeEmpresarial,NomeFantasia,SituacaoCadastral,DataSituacaoCadastral,MotivoSituacaoCadastral,NomeCidadeExterior,CodigoPais,NomePais,CodigoNaturezaJuridica,DataInicioAtividade,CnaeFiscal,DescricaoTipoLogradouro,Logradouro,Numero,Complemento,Bairro,Cep,Uf,CodigoMunicipio,Municipio,Ddd1,Telefone1,Ddd2,Telefone2,NuDddFax,NuFax,CorreioEletronico,QualificacaoResponsavel,CapitalSocialEmpresa,PorteEmpresa,OpcaoPeloSimples,DataOpcaoPeloSimples,DataExclusaoSimples,OpcaoPeloMei,SituacaoEspecial,DataSituacaoEspecial,Filler,FimDeRegistro)
                select rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,1,1))) as TipoRegistro
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,2,1))) as IndicadorFullDiario
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,3,1))) as TipoAtualizacao
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,4,14))) as Cnpj
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,18,1))) as IdentificadorMatrizFilial
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,19,150))) as RazaoSocialNomeEmpresarial
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,169,55))) as NomeFantasia
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,224,2))) as SituacaoCadastral
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,226,8))) as DataSituacaoCadastral
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,234,2))) as MotivoSituacaoCadastral
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,236,55))) as NomeCidadeExterior
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,291,3))) as CodigoPais
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,294,70))) as NomePais
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,364,4))) as CodigoNaturezaJuridica
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,368,8))) as DataInicioAtividade
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,376,7))) as CnaeFiscal
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,383,20))) as DescricaoTipoLogradouro
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,403,60))) as Logradouro
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,463,6))) as Numero
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,469,156))) as Complemento
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,625,50))) as Bairro
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,675,8))) as Cep
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,683,2))) as Uf
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,685,4))) as CodigoMunicipio
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,689,50))) as Municipio
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,739,4))) as Ddd1
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,743,8))) as Telefone1
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,751,4))) as Ddd2
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,755,8))) as Telefone2
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,763,4))) as NuDddFax
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,767,8))) as NuFax
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,775,115))) as CorreioEletronico
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,890,2))) as QualificacaoResponsavel
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,892,14))) as CapitalSocialEmpresa
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,906,2))) as PorteEmpresa
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,908,1))) as OpcaoPeloSimples
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,909,8))) as DataOpcaoPeloSimples
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,917,8))) as DataExclusaoSimples
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,925,1))) as OpcaoPeloMei
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,926,23))) as SituacaoEspecial
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,949,8))) as DataSituacaoEspecial
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,957,243))) as Filler
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,1200,1))) as FimDeRegistro
            --End

            Goto Continuar;
        end;

        -- CNAE Segundario
        if (@TipoRegistro = '6')
        begin
            Set @TotalRegistros6 = @TotalRegistros6 + 1;

            Select @Cnpj = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,4,14))), @CnaeSecundaria = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,18,7)));

            If Exists (Select Id From CnaeSecundario Where Cnpj = @Cnpj and CnaeSecundaria = @CnaeSecundaria)
            Begin
                Update CnaeSecundario with (tablock)
                    Set TipoRegistro = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,1,1)))
                        ,IndicadorFullDiario = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,2,1)))
                        ,TipoAtualizacao = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,3,1)))
                        ,Filler = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,711,489)))
                        ,FimRegistro = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,1200,1)))
                Where Cnpj = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,4,14)))
                    And CnaeSecundaria = rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,18,7)))
            End
            Else
            Begin
                Insert into CnaeSecundario with (tablock) (TipoRegistro,IndicadorFullDiario,TipoAtualizacao,Cnpj,CnaeSecundaria,Filler,FimRegistro)
                select rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,1,1))) as TipoRegistro
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,2,1))) as IndicadorFullDiario
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,3,1))) as TipoAtualizacao
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,4,14))) as Cnpj
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,18,7))) as CnaeSecundaria
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,711,489))) as Filler
                        ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,1200,1))) as FimRegistro
            --End;

            Goto Continuar;
        end;

        -- Trailler
        if (@TipoRegistro = '9')
        begin
            insert Into Trailler (TipoRegistro,Filler1,TotalRegistrosT1,TotalRegistrosT2,TotalRegistrosT3,TotalRegistros,Filler2,FimDeRegistro)
            Select rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,1,1))) as TipoRegistro
                    ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,2,16))) as Filler
                    ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,18,9))) as TotalRegistrosT1
                    ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,27,9))) as TotalRegistrosT2
                    ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,36,9))) as TotalRegistrosT3
                    ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,45,11))) as TotalRegistros
                    ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,56,1144))) as Filler
                    ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,1200,1))) as FimDeRegistro

            Goto Continuar;
        end;

                -- Header
        if (@TipoRegistro = '0')
        begin
            Insert Into Header (TipoRegistro,Filler1,NomeArquivo,DataGravacao,NumeroRemessa,Filler2,FimRegistro)
            select rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,1,1))) as TipoRegistro
                    ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,2,16))) as Filler
                    ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,18,11))) as NomeArquivo
                    ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,29,8))) as DataGravacao
                    ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,37,8))) as NumeroRemessa
                    ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,45,1155))) as Filler
                    ,rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(@linha,1200,1))) as FimRegistro;

            Goto Continuar;
        end;

        -- Erro
        if (@TipoRegistro <> '0' and @TipoRegistro <> '1' and @TipoRegistro <> '2' and @TipoRegistro <> '6' and @TipoRegistro <> '9')
        begin
            Insert Into LogImportacao (Linha,Mensagem,DataEvento) Values (@linha,'Layout não configurado para a linha processada', getdate());
        end;

        Continuar:
            Fetch Next From cCarga Into @linha;
    End;

    print @TotalRegistros;

    Close cCarga;
    Deallocate cCarga;

    Insert Into LogImportacao (Linha,Mensagem,DataEvento) Values ('Resumo Processamento','Total Registros: [' + cast(@TotalRegistros as varchar(max)) + '] Total Registros 1: [' + cast(@TotalRegistros1 as varchar(max)) + '] Total Registros 2: [' + cast(@TotalRegistros2 as varchar(max)) + '] Total Registros 6: [' + cast(@TotalRegistros6 as varchar(max))+']', getdate());
end;
```

It wastaking hours and hours ( more than 15 ) to import only 1 million rows. After Some indexes, we could improve the `IF EXISTS` performance to something instantly.

But we let this procedure running for 2 days, only importing 30Million rows. Is there a way to improve this cursor? even not using it?

with PK or not, the performance is the same.

Comment: Which part ran for two days? Was there blocking? Was it making progress? Why does your update need a `TABLOCK` hint? Why do single row inserts need it?

Comment: This is the full cursor. if exists, it inserts in the table based on the first number of the row. it was yes making progress, we could import ~20million rows in 2 days. we used TABLOCK to test something to not fulfill the LOG. what do you mean by "single row inserts?, It's because we will be using this method again each 3 months. in the next month there will be data, and if iit already exists, we should update. In this first time yes we could only insert, but it will fail in the next time because of performance. Thanks Erik.

Comment: Ohh and I got the "using tablock in single rows" part. Sorry my englihs is not the best haha. we were trying the same, using tablock to not fill the log file. SOmething funny is, during the trace I could see every operation was taking 0 milliseconds. I think after some time, it starts to be slow because of the index I created on the tables ( only one on ID with include ).